# Matrix Transpose as a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

As linear transformations, are the $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $A^T$ (transpose of $A$) related in any way, other than being transposes?

Comment: Read about dual spaces,

Comment: Same determinant, trace, rank, minimal and characteristic polynomials, ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the key property satisfied by the transpose of $A$ is
$$
\langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, A^T y \rangle
$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$.

**Further information:**
If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional inner product spaces over $F$ (where $F$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$), and $T: V \to W$ is a linear transformation, then the adjoint of $T$ is defined to be the linear transformation $T^*:W \to V$ which satisfies $\langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, T^* y \rangle$ for all $x \in V, y \in W$.  It's interesting to think about how the matrix representation of $T^*$ is related to the matrix representation of $T$.